# Hash selection function throwing an error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I want to use the hash as an ID selector using jQuery but I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#o1w609accordion'
at Function.fa.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at fa.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at fa.select (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.fa (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at n.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

This is my JavaScript code. It grabs the hash value, and then I want to use it as an ID selector.

```
export default {
init() {
// JavaScript to be fired on all pages

  $(document).ready(function(){
      if(window.location.hash) {
          var hash = window.location.hash;
          $('.accordion').attr('data-accordion','06i9fb-accordion');
          $(`'${hash}'`).css('display','block');
          $('.accordion a[href="' + hash + '"]').trigger('click');
      }
  });
},
 finalize() {
  // JavaScript to be fired on all pages, after page specific JS is fired
 },
};
```

Comment: What is `${hash}`? If you are trying to access an element by its ID, then it should be `$("#ID_OF_THE_ELEMENT")`

Comment: Remove the single quotes? -> `$(\`${hash}\`)`

Comment: @MilanChheda it's an ES2015 template string variable.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Oh Ok. Got it. My bad.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I guess OP has used templated correctly as value is coming in error `unrecognized expression: '#o1w609accordion'`

Comment: To make it more readable try using `$('#'+hash)` instead.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, OP did use the template correctly, but the string value isn't a valid CSS selector.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're mixing ES6 with non-ES6 code? Since your template string in line 9 can be utilised in line 10 as well.

Comment: it's a habbit :P I refactored all this code to es6(trying to get a habbit to write es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many `'` in your selector.

The jquery error for an unrecognized expression is (for `$("{")`):

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {

while your error is:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#o1w609accordion'

so your, translated, expression is:

```
$("'#o1w609accordion'")
```

Remove the extra `'` and you should be ok, possibly:

```
$(`${hash}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#'+hash).css('display','block');
```

your problem is in your selector

Comment: This works, and is a valid solution, but doesn't describe the actual answer to the problem.

Comment: you are missing the # of the ID Selector, maybe if you do

$(`'#${hash}').css('display','block');

Comment: @PatrickSampaio if the `#` was missing, the error would not include the `#`